# Authentication without has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm trying to do a custom authentication to better understand what's going on under the hood. It took a while to get it to accept password and password_confirmation, but now it just wont work and I'm all out of ideas

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    par = params[:user]
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.verify_password_confirmation(par[:password], par[:password_confirmation]) && @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to user_url(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any danger to having password and password_confirmation in attr_accessor?

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation, :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  before_save { email.downcase! }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d]\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true,
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def password=(password)
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end

  def verify_password(password) #for the sessions, which obviously I can't check yet
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest) == password
  end

  def verify_password_confirmation(pass, pass_con) #couldn't see how else to confirm it
    pass_con == pass
  end

  def reset_session_token!
    self.session_token = SecureRandom::base64(32)
    self.save!

    self.session_token
  end
end
```

EDIT: Specifically the problem is that it's failing at either the `@user.save` or the `verify_password_confirmation` and re-rendering

Comment: what is the error/which part is not working?

Comment: As well, in the verify_password method you should be comparing self.password_digest == BCrypt::Password.new(password)

Comment: DON'T do custom auth, you'll do it wrong. If you want to learn read the code of Devise gem for example.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel, it's just a learning project so I'm not worried about someone breaking in. That being said no one has answered me so I guess I'll move on.

Comment: @MCB that's event better. Reading code is the best way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Look at secure_password.rb on github. has_secure_password is much more simple, clear and easy to understand than other third party authentication gems or plugins.
Also note that has_secure_password uses bcrypt-ruby gem for generating password_digest. So if you want to roll your own authenticating system then you will want to think about its security as well.

Comment: I already switched to `has_secure_password`, the project is never going to go live, it is just practice. And part of that practice was to mess around with auth without the helpers. But, I have other aspects that I wanted to work on more so I just moved on.